# How to call rest apis async and wait untill all calls are done in rx-android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-android

In an activity i need to call 4 rest API. One API does not depends on another. But for a calculation I need data of all 4 APIs. So, I'm planning to call APIs asynchronous but wait until all API are done loading. I'm using RxAndroid with retrofit. I don't know how to achieve this using rx. I don't want to use a Boolean  for each API call to track if it loaded or not. Is there any rx way?

For now, I synchronize all calls like below

Sample code:

```
fun getData() {
    val disposable = dataSource.getLivePayments()
                        .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                        .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
                        .subscribe(({ livePayments: List<Payment> ->
                            this.livePayments.clear()
                            this.livePayments.addAll(livePayments)

                            dataSource.getLiveRemittances()
                                .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                                .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
                                .subscribe(({ liveRemittances: List<Remittance> ->
                                    this.liveRemittances.clear()
                                    this.liveRemittances.addAll(liveRemittances)

                                    // similarly called dataSource.getLiveTimeSheets()
                                    // and dataSource.getArchiveTimeSheets()
                                    // synchronous
                                    // then call 
                                    calculateAmount()
                                }), ({ t -> this.parseError(t) }))
                        }), ({ t -> this.parseError(t) }))

    compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
}

fun calculateAmount() {
 val balance = if(liveRemittances.isNotEmpty()) {
    (sum(payment.amount) - sum(timesheet.amount)) * sum(liveRemittance.amount)
    } else {
        (sum(payment.amount) - sum(timesheet.amount))
    }
}
```

**NB:** In this procedure, if some API fails, it stop executing next API but i want it should call next API.

Comment: The remittance doesn't depend on the payment in any way (doesn't accept it as input), so why do you need "callback hell" here?

Comment: You can try the combineLastest operator.

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't know :P I'm learning Rx, & trying to simplify this.

Comment: I feel like you want `getLivePayments().flatMap(payment -> dataSource.getLiveRemittances(payment)).flatMap(remittance -> dataSource.getArchiveTimeSheets(remittance))`, where you get each object based on the previous input. That way, you're not downloading all timesheets, for example, only those for that payment/remittance combination

Comment: No, each object is independent. I have a calculation where i need payment, remittance and time sheets data

Comment: i've provided some more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the API calls are independent you can use the [`zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator:

```
Single.zip(single1, single2, ..., (result1, result2, ... -> (combine the results)})
```

If the have dependant results you can use [`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)

```
single1.flatMap(result -> (generate a new Single based on that result)})
```

Comment: Will you please give me some example? or give me some tutorial link?

Comment: I added the link to the official documentation :S

Comment: I feel like flatmap only makes sense if you want to "get a timesheet of a remittance for a list of payments"

Comment: I'm trying Single.zip, I'll update about it. Any other approach is highly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: zip simplified it. But 1. calling is still synchronous (I want it asynchronous). 2. if any observable return to `onError()`, it cancel all next observable (i want it proceed with next observable). Is it possible to meet these requirement.

Comment: Every RxJava code is synchronous *unless* you specify it otherwise with [`subscribeOn`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html) or [`observeOn`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html). If you want to execute something in case of error you'll have to handle it. You have [several options](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/catch.html)